# How to show a popup in chrome extension just on a single condition on OnClick event?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

Hi I am in need to show a popup just once during installation of the extension asking for username and a log in button.When the user first clicks on the extension icon,a pop up should appear asking for username.when the user enters his username correctly,and clicks login,the pop up should be closed and then when the user again clicks on the extension icon,it should navigate to a website.What I did is when the user enters his username,it is stored in the localStorage,Each time when the user clicks on the extension icon,it checks for whether there is username in localstorage.if yes,then it should navigate to website otherwise,it should show the popup again.How can this be done?Please help me.
Here is my background.js

```
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
 if(!localStorage.username){
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
    popup: "userinfo.html"
   }); 
   }
else{//navigate to website }
```

});

Here the problem is that when the user first clicks on the icon,the pop up appears and the user enters his name and login.Next time when i click it again shows the pop up only.IT is not navigating to the website.Until i reload the extension,it shows only the popup on the onclick event.Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a listener for the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` event that checks if the username is stored in localStorage and:

1. if it is there navigate to the website.
2. if it is not there navigate to `userinfo.html` (either in a new tab or opening a new popu window (using **[`chrome.windows.create()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)**), which enables you to define its location and size).
3. when submitting the username and password in your `userinfo.html` page you can store them in localStorage **and** log the user in.

E.g.:

**In *background.js*:**

```
var myWebsite = 'https://your.domain.goes/here';
var myUserinfo = chrome.extension.getURL('userinfo.html');
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    if (localStorage.username) {
        /* Navigate to website */
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: myWebsite });
    } else {
        /* Navigate to `userifo.html` */
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: myUserinfo });
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    if ((msg.action === 'saveCredentials')
            && msg.user && msg.pass) {

        /* Store the credentials in localStorage */
        localStorage.username = user;
        localStorage.password = pass;

        /* For a better user-experience, let's
         * navigate the user to the website right away */
        chrome.tabs.updated(sender.tab.id, { url: myWebsite });
    }
});
```

**In *userinfo.html*'s JS:**

```
// ...once the userinfo is "submitted"
var user = ...;
var pass = ...;
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: 'saveCredentials',
    user: user,
    pass: pass
});
```

Comment: NP. Don't forget to accept/upvote if it helped you solve your problem :)

Comment: Hey,but I need not want to open the pop up in a new window/tab.I want just near the omni box.ie,when i click on the icon,it should appear just below the icon.

Comment: I believe the best approach is to open it in a new tab. Once the user enters the credentials, you will redirect him/her to the website (right in the same tab). Why don't you like it ?

Comment: Yeah.I have already done it to work in a new tab.But now I am asked to do it in the same tab.so i am helpless.How can I do it?Is it possible?

Comment: It is but it is complicated (knowing your background-page ;)). `chrome.browserAction.setPopup()` is your friend here, but when and how to call it is a little complex. I'll take a look later to see what I can come up with (maybe it is not so complex after all :D)

Comment: Do you need my background.js completely?Should I include in my post?I hope you understand my problem??

Comment: Since most of your background is based on my answers here on SO, I don't think it will be necessary :P

Comment: Hey,sorry,no need to try it.since it is complicated,just leave it.sorry.

Comment: Does this mean that this answer covers you and solves the problem ?

Comment: No but I am asked to do in another way.I shall post that as a different question.Can you please check it?

Comment: Hey can you please check this link??http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563879/how-to-add-action-buttons-in-a-popup-and-navigate-to-a-website-in-chrome-extensi

Comment: OK, I will take a look. Still, if you think this answer is useful and could solve a similar problem, consider marking it as accepted/upvoting, for future visitors.