# How to add action buttons in a popup and navigate to a website in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I am in need to a show 2 pop ups on 2 different situation.Presently I am checking a server file and storing its credentials in a localStorage.Each time when the user clicks on the extension,it should check if the localStorage is empty or not.If it is empty,then a pop up should be seen and asks for his username.this is stored in localstorage.Next time when the user clicks on the icon,the localstorage is not empty,so it should show another pop up showind a field for username  with 2 buttons namely 'change settings' and 'go to website'.When the user clicks on change settings,again the popup shuuld appear asking user name.If he clicks go to website,it should navigate to a website.How can this be done?please help me.I have tried button the button is not working.And also the 2nd pop up is always shown only on reloading the extension.Please help me.
Here is my background.js

here is my updated popup.js

```
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {   
  var divLoading  = document.querySelector('div#loadingContainer');
  var divSettings = document.querySelector('div#settingsContainer');
  var divLoggedIn = document.querySelector('div#loggedInContainer');
  var divChange = document.querySelector('div#settingsChange');


 var user1 = divSettings.querySelector('input#user1');
 var form  = divSettings.querySelector('form#userinfo');


 var user2   = divLoggedIn.querySelector('span#user2');   
 var change  = divLoggedIn.querySelector('input#change');
 var calpine = divLoggedIn.querySelector('input#calpine');

 var user3 = divChange.querySelector('input#user3');
 var form3  = divChange.querySelector('input#changeset');
 var cancel = divChange.querySelector('input#emailcancel');


 var user = localStorage.username;
  if (user) {

   // user1.value = user2.value = user;
   user1.value = user2.textContent = user;
    user3.value = user;        
    divLoggedIn.style.display = 'block';
    divSettings.style.display = 'none';
    divChange.style.display = 'none';      
    } else {

    divSettings.style.display = 'block';
    divChange.style.display = 'none';
    divLoggedIn.style.display = 'none';      
    user1.focus();
    user1.select();
    }
   divLoading.style.display = 'none';


    form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var userStr = user1.value;
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
        bgPage.login(userStr);
    });
    window.close();
     });

   form3.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var userStr = user3.value;

    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
        bgPage.login(userStr);
    });
    window.close();
    });

   change.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    divLoggedIn.style.display = 'none';
    divSettings.style.display = 'none';
    divChange.style.display = 'block';

    user3.focus();
    user3.select();
   });

   cancel.addEventListener('click', function() {
    divLoggedIn.style.display = 'block';
    divSettings.style.display = 'none';
    divChange.style.display = 'none';

    user3.focus();
    user3.select();
    });


    calpine.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'http://www.calpinemate.com/' });
    });
    });
```

I have made some changed as i was asked to do so.I have added a new div named divchange.
here is my updated userinfo.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="popbak.js"></script>       
  </head>
     <body>

    <div id="loadingContainer"></div>
    <div id="settingsContainer">
        <b>Please Enter your Email ID/Employee Code</b>
        <br />
        <br />
        <form id="userinfo">
            <table>
                <tr><td> <label for="user">Email/Employee Code:</label></td>
                    <td>    <input type="text" id="user1" required /></td></tr>
                <tr><td> <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log In" /></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
       </div>
       <div id="settingsChange">
        <b>Please Enter your Email ID/Employee Code</b>
        <br />
        <br />

            <table>
                <tr><td><label for="user">Email/Employee Code:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="user3" required /></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="button" id="emailchange" value="Change" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" id="emailcancel" value="Cancel" /></td>                         </tr>
               </table>

        </div> 

      <div id="loggedInContainer">
        <table>
            <tr><td>   <label for="user">Email/Employee Code:</label></td>

      <!--   <input type="text" id="user2" readonly /> -->
         <td><span id="user2"></span></td> </tr>   
        <br />
        <tr><td><input type="button" id="calpine" value="Go to Calpinemate"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="change" value="Change Settings"/></td></tr>
        </table>
         </div>
         </body>
      </html>
```

here is my bgpage.login()

```
   function login(useremail){
     if(!useremail)
    {
  alert('Please enter your Email/Employee code');  //this is not working
 return;
   } 
  var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
   var urlSuffix = '/3';
   var req1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req1.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {   
    if (req1.readyState == 4) {
    if (req1.status == 200) {          
    var item=req1.responseText;           
    if(item==1){
     localStorage.username=useremail;  
                 updateIcon();             
     }
      else
       {
           alert('Please enter a valid Email/employee code');
               updateIcon();

       }
     }
    else {
      alert("ERROR: status code " + req1.status);
     }
      }
       });

   var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(useremail) + urlSuffix;
   req1.open("GET", url);    
    req1.send(null);       
    }
```

Here is my background.js

```
var myNotificationID = null;
 var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;


  setInterval(function() {
      updateIcon();
      }, 1000); 

     function getGmailUrl() {
        return "http://calpinemate.com/";

      }


      function isGmailUrl(url) {
      return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;

          }




    function onInit() {

   updateIcon();

       if (!oldChromeVersion) { 

       chrome.alarms.create('watchdog',{periodInMinutes:5,delayInMinutes:  0}); 
     }

          }



        function onAlarm(alarm) {

         if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {

             onWatchdog();

            } 

        else {

         updateIcon();

       }


   function onWatchdog() {

     chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {

       if (alarm) {

      console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');

          } 
     else {
   updateIcon();

      }
    });

     }



     if (oldChromeVersion) {
       updateIcon(); 
        onInit();

          } 

       else {

    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);

        chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);

     }




    function updateIcon(){
      if(localStorage.username){

    var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
     var urlSuffix = '/2';

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

     req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {

              if (req.readyState == 4) {

            if (req.status == 200) {


       var item=req.responseText;


       if(item==1){

        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_logged_in.png"});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""});  

        chrome.notifications.clear('id1', function(){});

         }

      else{

       chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"calpine_not_logged_in.png"});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[190, 190, 190, 230]});

       chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""}); 

       chrome.notifications.create(
       'id1',{
       type: 'basic',
       iconUrl: '/calpine_not_logged_in.png',
       title: 'Warning : Attendance',
        message: 'Please mark your Attendance !',
       buttons: [{ title: 'Mark',
                        iconUrl: '/tick.jpg'
                  },{ title: 'Ignore',
                        iconUrl: '/cross.jpg'}],
       priority: 0},
       function(id) { myNotificationID = id;}
     );    

        }

      } 
   else {

        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);

       }

    }

          });
   var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.username) + urlSuffix;
    req.open("GET", url);


   req.send(null);
     }
    }



     onInit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the localStorage of the background-page and that of the popup are <strike>not</strike> the same objects. <strike>Besides, each time the popup is shown, it is loaded anew, thus the localStorage is empty.</strike>
***UPDATE: Thx to rsanchez's comment, I correct my mistake: the popup shares the localStorage object of the extension (which is the same as the one of the background-page).***
You should use the localStorage of the background-page. (Keep in mind this works **only** because you have a persistent background-page !)

The simplest (and most reliable) way is to have a single popup with two different divs (one for entering credentials and one for logging in) and display only one at a time.

E.g.:

1) Remove any `chrome.browserAction.onClicked...` listener from the background-page (it won't hurt leaving it there as it will never be triggered, but it will confuse you in the future).

2) Declare a popup in your manifest (if you don't have already done do):

```
<pre>
...
"browser_action": {
    ...
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
...
</pre>
```

3). Create a file named `popup.html` with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loadingContainer"><h3>Loading...</h3></div>
        <div id="settingsContainer" style="display:none;">
            <b>Enter your Email ID/Employee Code</b>
            <br />
            <br />
            <form id="userinfo">
                <label for="user">Email/Employee Code:</label>
                <input type="text" id="user1" required />
                <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log In" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="loggedInContainer" style="display:none;">
            <label for="user">Email/Employee Code:</label>
            <!--<input type="text" id="user2" readonly />-->
            <span id="user2"></span>
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="calpine" value="Go to Calpinemate"/>
            <input type="button" id="change" value="Change Settings"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
</pre>
```

4) Create a file named `popup.js` with the following code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    /* Container divs */
    var divLoading  = document.querySelector('div#loadingContainer');
    var divSettings = document.querySelector('div#settingsContainer');
    var divLoggedIn = document.querySelector('div#loggedInContainer');

    /* Settings-container fields */
    var user1 = divSettings.querySelector('input#user1');
    var form  = divSettings.querySelector('form#userinfo');

    /* LoggedIn-container fields */
    //var user2   = divLoggedIn.querySelector('input#user2');
    var user2   = divLoggedIn.querySelector('span#user2');
    var change  = divLoggedIn.querySelector('input#change');
    var calpine = divLoggedIn.querySelector('input#calpine');

    /* Query the extension's localStorage
     * in order to decide which DIV to show */
    var user = localStorage.username;
    if (user) {
        /* 'Username' is set: Show the LoggedIn-container
         * (after updating the value of the (readonly) '#user' field) */
        //user1.value = user2.value = user;
        user1.value = user2.textContent = user;
        divLoggedIn.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        /* 'Username' is not set: Show the Settings-container */
        divSettings.style.display = 'block';
        user1.focus();
        user1.select();
    }
    divLoading.style.display = 'none';

    /* Listener for '#userinfo' form */
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var userStr = user1.value;
        chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bgPage) {
            bgPage.login(userStr);
        });
        window.close();
    });

    /* Listener for '#change' button */
    change.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        divLoggedIn.style.display = 'none';
        divSettings.style.display = 'block';
        user1.focus();
        user1.select();
    });

    /* Listener for '#calpine' button */
    calpine.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://your.domain.goes/here' });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey I have another question to ask.But I have no permission to ask any questions from my account.So I am asking here.Please help me.

Comment: Please, take the time to find out what is wrong with your account and fix it. There is a reason that you are not allowed to ask questions :)

Comment: I need to know how to set 2 time intervals for the same function?I mean that, now i have set timeinterval of 1 sec to continuously monitor the output of server file.If the output of server file is 0,then color of extension icon changes and it shows a notification.Now the problem is that i have written both these functionalities in the same functon.

Comment: So as i have set time interval for 1 sec and call that function,the notification shows every 1 sec and the color of icon also changes every 1 sec based on server output,which is fine.Now what I need is that i need to change the color every 1 sec.but i need to show notification only every 5 min.can you please help me.i have posted my background.js.can you please help me?

Comment: Please, read my previous comment. I won't answer questions through comments. This site is a great place for developer to be, so lets stick to the rules and keep it that way !

Comment: ok.but what should i do to post another question?they won't accept my question.And what can I do for my previous questions?i have accepted and upvoted all the answers that helped me.and now what should i do?

Comment: if you know the answer of my question,why can't you help me?Ans someone else has downvoted my question.so what can i do for that?

Comment: Learn more about why your accounted is "banned" and what you can do about it **[here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)** and **[there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)**. Most importantly: learn from your mistakes in order not to repeat them in the future !